# Image not shown at exported HTML table as excel using php

Tags: html, excel

I am trying to export this HTML table to excel. But the image is only visible when there is internet available as the image source contains a link.

I want image to be visible in the excel sheet when the table is exported to excel sheet and the excel sheet is opened offline.

Is there any way to download the Excel and open it in offline mode to see the image?

My HTML:

```html
<table class="table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
    <tbody><tr>
     <th>Justification</th>
     <th>Components</th>
     <th class="text-center" align="center">Offer</th>
     <th class="text-center" align="center">Measurement Unit</th>
     <th class="text-center" align="center">Rate</th>
     <th class="text-center" align="center">Value</th>
     <th class="text-center" align="center">FV Allocation</th>
    </tr>
<tr><td colspan="7" ><img width="60" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" ></td></tr>
    
        <tr>
     <td>Purchase Price</td>
     <td>Device</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Pcs</td>
     <td class="text-right">30,900.00</td>
     <td class="text-right">30,900.00</td>
     <td class="text-right">57.53%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>NC</td>
     <td>On-net Mins</td>
     <td>21528</td>
     <td>Mins</td>
     <td class="text-right">0.40</td>
     <td class="text-right">8,611.20</td>
     <td class="text-right">16.03%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>NC</td>
     <td>Off-net Mins</td>
     <td>9672</td>
     <td>Mins</td>
     <td class="text-right">0.84</td>
     <td class="text-right">8,124.48</td>
     <td class="text-right">15.13%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>NC</td>
     <td>SMS</td>
     <td>1200</td>
     <td>Count</td>
     <td class="text-right">0.15</td>
     <td class="text-right">180.00</td>
     <td class="text-right">0.34%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>NC</td>
     <td>Data</td>
     <td>24576</td>
     <td>MB</td>
     <td class="text-right">0.24</td>
     <td class="text-right">5,898.24</td>
     <td class="text-right">10.98%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="text-right fbold">53,713.92</td>
     <td class="text-right fbold">100%</td>
    </tr>

   </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Maybe by encoding the image as base64 inside its src attribute? Google with "base64 encoded image src attribute" to get the right syntax.

Comment: I have already tried this way, but excel not showing the base64 encoded image. :(

Comment: If you are sure of the syntax, I don't see another way. Don't forget you are opening an html file in Excel (kind of an import), not a xlsx file (native excel format)

Comment: I have used `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");`, so it will not native excel format I think.

Comment: Same problem here! I also need solution of this.

Comment: no it's plain html and excel importing it (the same way it can import CSV files or any other data). Content-type is not relevant in this case

Comment: Using base64 encoded: `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo $b64image; ?>" />` The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location. screenshot [link](http://prntscr.com/im7x38)